# Simulink signal from data generated by a fcn() block

Tags: matlab, simulink

In simulink I have a function block. Basically it contains

```
function y=fcn(u)
if u==1
    a=[0,...,1]; 
    b=[1,...,2];
end
y=[a',b'];
%y=struct('time',a,'value',b); %Second option
```

I want to use these arrays as a signal. As you see I have tried two options, making an output as an array and as a structure, non of them work for me.

In short, I'd like to be able to connect a scope to the output of the function and see the signal generated by `(a,b)`. The reason I want to do it from a Simulink block is that I can just switch between many options of signals without having to build again the model. More over, I'd prefer that if the simulation time is bigger than whatever is specified in `a` then the signal keeps the last value of `b`.

p.s. I have tried this using a `From Workspace` block and it works fine.

Comment: " non of them work for me". Why?

Comment: I think that simulink interpret each value of the array as one constant vector. Then for example if `a` and `b` have 100 elements, Simulink thinks of them as 100 distinct constants. When I used `From Workspace` I could specify the time and the data values, use interpolation (I gues to the Simulink time) and had the option to hold the last value of the data. I'd like to do the same but from a function block on simulink.

Comment: well of course. A function block is called each timestep of the runtime. If in each of the timesteps you output 100 values, then in each of the timesteps the block will have 100 outputs. Is that your problem?

Comment: I guess that's indeed the problem. So, maybe I am doing things completely wrong, I'll think again. Plainly, what I want is: A block in Simulink that generates data once, say at the beginning of simulation, that's it (not every time step). Then use this data as a "time-signal".

Comment: You can make Simulink to run a `.m` file once before the execution.

Comment: You mean to use `InitFcn` ?

Comment: I think so, yes. Yo ucan put your singal there

Comment: That is indeed a solution, thanks.